# Kotlin data class: member not getting initialized when using as a retrofit response

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, data-class

```
data class A (val x: Array<String>? = null) {
    val y = x?.filter { it!="something" }
}
```

This code should make member `y` to be calculated when an `A` object is created.

When I initiate an `A` object, both `x` and `y` gets a value.
However, when I define object `A` as a response in a `GET` request using `retrofit2`, `x` gets a value but `y` is `null`.
I cannot figure out the reason, (maybe relative to threads? I am using retrofit with coroutines), but can not explain it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this even compile? If `x` is nullable, `x.filter` shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: You're right. Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note: Your filter doesn't do anything, because your input array cannot contain nulls.

Comment: right. corrected again

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on which `Converter.Factory` you use for Retrofit, but yours probably uses reflection in a way which doesn't actually call the constructor. I'd try [`MoshiConverterFactory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/converter-moshi/retrofit2/converter/moshi/MoshiConverterFactory.html) (if your GET response is JSON) and see if it fixes the problem.